# Tracing Office-365 Outlook invite updates in a Hybrid environment

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Project manager recently sent a "In-Person" mandatory meeting invite (Office 365 Outlook) and then later made a small change to the Details of the Meeting. I don't think they chose to send an update when they made those changes, as I don't recall receiving an email with them.

Is there a way to trace when the invite was updated?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your version of the meeting show the change? If so, your Outlook client is set to auto process updates to meetings.

This is the normal/default setting for Outlook. So long as key aspects such as the date and time aren't changing, Outlook will automatically process changes made to meetings you have accepted and delete the updated invites. On a related note, the invite is NOT the meeting. Do not use the one word to mean the other.

You can find the processed updated invites in your Deleted Items folder.

For further investigation you can ask your Exchange admins and they have tools for tracing this.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly was the meeting uptated? If the meeting organizer added a new attendee and choose to **Send updates only to added or deleted attendees**, you will not receive the meeting updates.

[image]

Comment: The body content of the invite was updated. But I never received the update, also checked Outlook's 'Deleted Items' folder, there was no calendar item related to this invite

Comment: Do other meeting attendees receive the meeting update message?